# R - CLARA clustering in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-analysis

Is it possible to perform CLARA clustering (clustering around medoids done by sampling) using parallel processing functionality of R? I have about 150000 points in 8 dimensions, so I need to cluster the samples, otherwise I there is no enough processing power in the world to cluster this.

Now, I am working on an iMac with one Dual-Core processor (2,4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo), so I am assuming I can use that in order to speed up the calculations. Since there are so many points, I need to perform many iterations of the clustering algorithm in order to find optimal number of clusters and optimal sample size ( although after a couple of experiments it seems like even with sample as small as 3000 the results are as good as with bigger samples). However, when the sample size approaches 5000, the computation slows down to days.

What is the best way of doing this in the latest version of R? I have read there is already built in parallel processing functionality (foreach, parallel packages). But the CLARA function is atomic in the sense that it is really difficult to modify its internal code to switch on parallel processing ( well, for me at least).

So, ideally I would like to run the internal code of CLARA function in parallel, as opposed to running iterations of this function with different parameters in parallel with each other.

Comment: have you already tried this in your laptop? It doesn't seem like a big dataset.